# Is window.document cleaned at page refresh ?

Tags: javascript, window

I was using the `window` object to save some values to have them accessible in other functions and a colleague of mine recommended me to save my data on `window.document` the reason being that the window.document is cleaned at every page load.

I was wondering if that is right because it's obvious that the DOM is reloaded but the other data like my modules i doubt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the page is reloaded, the entire DOM is rebuilt and the `window` object is scrubbed (probably it's a completely new object, though that's up to the browser).  Nothing survives from the previous page except local storage and cookies. Oh, and I guess you could count the history too.

That means that as the new page loads, and it reloads your JavaScript libraries, those are completely fresh copies, and they're initialized all over again.

Comment: This is *usually* the case, however, I've found that in some situations, Chrome will not properly scrub `window`/`document`/global scope when you return to a page using the back button. It's a little bit unpredictable, I haven't been able to nail down exactly how it handles this. This could be considered to not exactly be a "page refresh" though.

Comment: i think is better to use the window in my case, i don't see any reason why use document.(i work only on IE7)

Comment: @Adrian well the "Back" button gets you back to a former page; it doesn't necessarily do a re-load. There's not much in the way of formal specification about that.

Comment: @Pointy Definitely... my point was just that there are situations where one might expect a full refresh and not get it. I know it's caused some very difficult-to-troubleshoot issues for me personally.